# How to set full height in flex layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex layout, and its code like following

```
<div class="navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item ">
        <a href="/dashboard">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
        <a href="/profile">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And its css like this

```
.navbar-collapse {
  display: flex !important;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: auto;
  flex-basis: auto;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.navbar-nav {
  margin-left: auto !important;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-item {
  display: inline-flex;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
  position: relative;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-item a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 0.1rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}
```

It looks like this

[image: ef]

The a element currently appears to have no height, and I want it to be as heigh as the parent element, how? Thank you.

Append:

The image shows what it looks like when I'm in chrome developer mode. Above is all my code.

Comment: Which is your parent? is it `.navbar-collapse`? Setting height to this element automatically updates the height of child elements.

Comment: have you reseted the default paddings and margins of both `ul` and `li`?

Comment: @Nitheesh  it doesn't work.

Comment: @tacoshy No, I don't

Comment: @Nitheesh Hello, to clearly describe my problem, I've shared the full code here. codepen.io/billm36/pen/wvPPopW, when the hover attribute of a link is actived, the background color isn't full of the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the default style of `ul` element.

`ul` has a default margin value of `1em` as below.

```
ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    padding-inline-start: 40px;
}
```

You have to override this and bring this to you anchor tag as padding, because you are handling the hover effect of anchor tag. So this value should be set as the padding so that this will not break the layout while hovering.

I have fixed that in the below snippet.

**Working Fiddle**

```css
.navbar-collapse {
    display: flex !important;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: auto;
    flex-basis: auto;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.navbar-nav {
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin: 0; /* Added */
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item {
    display: inline-flex;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
    position: relative;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item a {
    color: black;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 0.1rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}

/* New styles added */
.navbar-nav .nav-item a {
    padding: 1em 0;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #6c757d;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    background-color: #00a82d;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <a href="/dashboard">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <a href="/profile">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented now the rest of your code from the fiddle within the comments. You need to give the `ul` a height of 100% of the parent: `.navbar-nav { height: 100%; }`. In my snippet you have in CSS-line 301 declared: `a { display: block; }` -> swap the value to `flex` to keep the text from the anchor centered.

```css
.navbar-nav { 
  height: 100%;  
}

.navbar-nav a {
  display: flex; /* swap this with line 301 */
}

/* original css */
html {
  line-height: 1.15;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%
}

body {
  margin: 0
}

main {
  display: block
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: .67em 0
}

hr {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible
}

pre {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  font-size: 1em
}

a {
  background-color: transparent
}

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 0;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration: underline dotted
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder
}

code,
kbd,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  font-size: 1em
}

small {
  font-size: 80%
}

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em
}

img {
  border-style: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.15;
  margin: 0
}

button,
input {
  overflow: visible
}

button,
select {
  text-transform: none
}

button,
[type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {
  border-style: none;
  padding: 0
}

button:-moz-focusring,
[type="button"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="reset"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="submit"]:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText
}

fieldset {
  padding: .35em .75em .625em
}

legend {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: inherit;
  display: table;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: normal
}

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto
}

[type="checkbox"],
[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0
}

[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto
}

[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  outline-offset: -2px
}

[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none
}

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  font: inherit
}

details {
  display: block
}

summary {
  display: list-item
}

template {
  display: none
}

[hidden] {
  display: none
}

html {
  font-size: 625%;
  font-family: "Roboto", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-size: 0.16rem;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #6c757d;
  line-height: 1.75;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.row {
  padding: 0 .12rem;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 0.32rem;
  color: #00a82d;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.125rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.125rem;
  line-height: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  display: flex!important;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: auto;
  flex-basis: auto;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-nav {
  margin-left: auto!important;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item {
  display: inline-flex;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
  position: relative;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.device-width {
  width: 9.6rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.usercenter-navbar {
  background-color: #00a82d;
  line-height: 1;
}

.usercenter .device-width {
  width: 98%;
}

.usercenter-navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: .28rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.usercenter-navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* display: block; */
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 0.1rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}

.usercenter-navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6c757d;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    font-size: 0.13rem;
  }
  .auth-form {
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .device-width {
    width: 11.4rem;
  }
  .auth-form {
    width: 22%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1920px) {
  .device-width {
    width: 11.4rem;
  }
  .auth-form {
    width: 20%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1919px) {
  .device-width {
    width: 11.4rem;
  }
  .auth-form {
    width: 26%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .device-width {
    width: 10.8rem;
  }
  .auth-form {
    width: 30%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .device-width {
    width: 9.6rem;
  }
  .auth-form {
    width: 30%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper usercenter">
  <div class="container usercenter-navbar">
    <div class="device-width">
      <div class="row">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Workspace</a>
        <div class="navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item  current">
              <a href="/dashboard">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ">
              <a href="/profile">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, to clearly describe my problem, I've shared the full code here. https://codepen.io/billm36/pen/wvPPopW, when the hover attribute of a link is actived, the background color isn't full of the height.

Comment: Ok adjusted my answer to your code. next time include your code as [repro] directly in the question. It makes the question more clear and the code easier to fix. It also waste less time of the users that try to fix an issue for you that fix a completely different CSS code.